Proof for monotonicity of function
Can someone prove the function $f(x)$ is monotonic $\forall x \in [0, n-1]$, while $n = 2, 3, \dots $. The function is as follows.
$$
f(x) = T_{n-1}(x) - T_n(x)
$$
where $T_n(x)$ is defined as,
$$
T_n(x) = \dfrac{\frac{x^n}{n!}}{\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{x^i}{i!}}
$$
I numerically checked $f(x)$ is monotonic by plotting it, but could not make mathematical proof yet. Any ideas?

Welcome to MSE! I am not among those who voted to close the question, but in the future you might want to give a bit more context, like for example elaborating a bit more on why you couldn't prove the monotonicity, what you tried even if just for small $n$s, or telling us if it's an exercise, a personal conjecture, etc... It doesn't have to be a long paragraph, but that'll dissuade other users from downvoting or closing the question, and in turn that will allow us to help you with more adequate comments or answers based on the tools and levels of maths you have access to.
